# WooCommerce Flatsome theme changing product image size

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I bought Flatsome theme for woocommerce. Need to significantly reduce the product image size on this page

http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/product/bjorn-tee-ss-jack-jones/

I could achieve this by changing the following line in the "inspect element" on chrome.
"div.large-6.columns.product-gallery"
to 
"div.large-2.columns.product-gallery"

But I don't understand how to change this in the source files.

I also unsuccessfully tried to change the image size in woocommerce -> settings -> Products -> Display. Regenerated Images.

I also unsuccessfully tried to change the size in Media -> Settings -> Large size & Medium Size

Would definitely appreciate the help at this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already overriding woocommerce templates, you an change the `div.large-2.columns.product-gallery` value you're talking about in:

> wp-content > themes > your theme > woocommerce > single-product >
>   product-image.php

You'll see:

```
<div class="large-6 columns product-gallery">
```

I assume that the theme is already doing that and you should be able to find the file I'm referring to. However, if the theme is not overriding the templates, you need to [learn about doing so](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) by reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can simply create a custom product page with ux builder (no coding) :
[Flatsome Docs](https://docs.uxthemes.com/article/245-how-to-create-a-custom-product-page)

Or creating a child theme and override woocommerce templates and/or Flatsome shortcodes.

To override Woocommerce templates in Flatsome put needed files from

```
'flatsome/woocommerce'
```

to your

`'child_theme/woocommerce'` directory and edit them.

Depending your product page layout options, the file to edit can change. See in :

`'flatsome/woocommerce/single_product/product-image-'` files and override what needed.